# Is it OK to combine domain specific word2vec embeddings and off the shelf ELMo embeddings for a downstream unsupervised task?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, training-data, word-embedding, elmo

I am wondering if I am using word embeddings correctly.

I have combined contextualised word vectors with static word vectors because:

- my domain corpus is too small to effectively train the model from scratch
- my domain is too specialised to use general embeddings.

I used the off the shelf ELMo small model and trained word2vec model on a small domain specific corpus (around 500 academic papers). I then did a simple concatenation of the vectors from the two different embeddings.

I loosely followed the approach in this paper:
https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P19-2041.pdf
But the approach in the paper trains the embeddings for a specific task. In my domain there is no labeled training data. Hence me just training the embeddings on the corpus alone.

I am new to NLP, so apologies if I am asking a stupid question.

Comment: Hi hi, this is actually a very interesting question. However, it is too broad for Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow works best when asked specific technical questions

Comment: Have you tried applying exactly the approach that paper proposes, to see how well it works on your data/domain/goal? ("Is it possible" is always a hard question to helpfully answer, because with enough effort/resources the answer is almost always "yes", but whether it's practical in some particular circumstances usually requires extensive details or just the feedback from actually trying lots of things with *exactly* your data/goals.)